# How to branch one edge into two using mxGraph?

Tags: mxgraph

I didn't find support for connecting one edge to another, thus right now I added a T-piece as a vertex for branching one edge into two edges:

[image: T-piece]

Now I'd like to be able to drag and drop the terminal of one edge onto another edge which should then create and connect a T-piece automatically. As a first step I thought about editing (or rather expanding) `getPreviewTerminalState` in `mxEdgeHandler` in order to highlight the target edge when a terminal point is dragged over it. However this feels quiet hacky since I naturally don't want to interfere with a function deep down in the library itself.

Is this the right starting point anyways? I just need a bit of guidance there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright by now I've found a solution I can live with and which makes the T-piece obsolete. If someone stumbles upon this issue too, the solution I have looks something like this:

```
// set edges as valid targets
var graphIsValidTarget = mxGraph.prototype.isValidTarget;
Graph.prototype.isValidTarget = function(cell) {
    return (cell && cell.edge) || graphIsValidTarget.apply(this, arguments);
};

// mark edge if another edge's terminal point is dragged over it
var edgeHandlerGetPreviewTerminalState = mxEdgeHandler.prototype.getPreviewTerminalState;
mxEdgeHandler.prototype.getPreviewTerminalState = function(me) {
    let ret = edgeHandlerGetPreviewTerminalState.apply(this, arguments);

    let edge = me.getCell();
    if (edge && edge.edge && this.graph.getSelectionCell() !== edge) {
        let state = this.graph.view.getState(edge);
        this.marker.setCurrentState(state, me, this.marker.validColor);
        ret = state;
    } else if (ret == null && this.marker && (!this.error || (this.error && this.error === ''))) {
        this.marker.reset();
    }

    return ret;
};

// snap to edge's midpoint
var graphViewGetFloatingTerminalPoint = mxGraphView.prototype.getFloatingTerminalPoint;
mxGraphView.prototype.getFloatingTerminalPoint = function(edge, start, end, source) {
    let res = null;

    if (start.edge) {
        res = this.graph.getEdgeMidPoint(start);
    } else {
        res = graphViewGetFloatingTerminalPoint.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return res;
};

// returns midpoint of an edge
Graph.prototype.getEdgeMidPoint = function(edge) {
    let ret = null;
    if (edge && edge.edge) {
        let points = this.view.getState(edge).absolutePoints;
        let minX = points[0].x < points[1].x ? points[0].x : points[1].x;
        let maxX = minX === points[0].x ? points[1].x : points[0].x;
        let minY = points[0].y < points[1].y ? points[0].y : points[1].y;
        let maxY = minY === points[0].y ? points[1].y : points[0].y;

        ret = new mxPoint(minX + (maxX - minX) / 2, minY + (maxY - minY) / 2);
    }
    return ret;
}
```